Помощь с deploy сайта на nic.ru
Я только разбираюсь в создании сайтов. Помогите понять, как это работает. У меня есть фронтенд часть моего сайта (React), по порту 5173. Есть серверная часть (ExpressJS), порт 3131. Связь между фронт и беком есть, и всё нормально работает.
Теперь появилась необходимость опубликовать этот сайт.
У меня есть хостинг nic.ru. Так вот, я могу залить на него я так понимаю только собранную фронтенд часть. А где мне хранить серверную часть на этом хостинге и как сделать связь между фронтенд и бекендом?

Вам нужен хостинг, который поддерживает nodeJs. Или же перейти на VPS
